# ActionScript2: Split a text with two delimiter, Help

Tags: string, actionscript-2, split

I try to create a project with use a Split in AC2.

this I have

```
    in_pers = 3x5+5x3+6x8;

var tmp:Array = in_pers.split("+");

trace(tmp);  //output ==  3x5, 5x3, 6x8
```

but, how if in_pers = 3x5+5x3-6x8-4x2;

how can I get the result 3x5, 5x3, 6x8, 4x2

how to use the split with two delimiter.

Best regard..

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to do what wikiup suggested:

```
function strReplace( haystack:String, needle:String, replacement:String ):String
{
    var tmpA:Array = haystack.split( needle );
    return tmpA.join( replacement );
}

function multiSplit( haystack:String, needles:Array ):Array
{
    // generate a unique String for concatenation.
    var salt:String = String( Math.random() ); //replace with anything you like

    // Replace all of the strings in the needles array with the salt variable
    for( var i:Number = 0; i < needles.length; i++ )
    {
        haystack = strReplace( haystack, needles[ i ], salt );
    }

    //haystack now only has the objects you want split up concatenated by the salt variable.
    //split haystack and you'll have your desired result.
    return haystack.split( salt );
}
```

Not only is this smaller, it is also faster (while takes a lot longer than for( i = 0; i < val; i++ ) (look up iteration vs. recursion) ).

Answer (score 2):

I know an even easier way:

```
var in_pers :String = "3x5+5x3-6x8";

var reg :RegExp = new RegExp ( "[+\-]" , "gi" );

trace ( in_pers.split ( reg ) ); // output: 3x5,5x3,6x8
```

that should do the trick.

the secret is to use RegExp class, witch is a little complicated to understand at first, because is shit-like documented and very confusing.

[+-] means "+" or "-" and in "gi" g is for global (match all patterns found, not just the first one) and i is for not case sensitive.

hope it helps anyone reading this...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, AS2 has no native understanding of regular expressions. To use RegExp, you'd have to move to AS3, or find a regular expression class written for AS2...there are some out there.

I think for this purpose you'd need to create a custom function. I'm not sure the one I've created below is the best...a bit kludgy and maybe not the most performant, but I think it does essentially what you need.

```
var in_pers:String = "3x5+5x3-6x8-4x2";
var tmp:Array = multiSplit(in_pers, ["+", "-"]);
trace (tmp);

function multiSplit(str:String, delimiters:Array):Array
{
    /* create an array to return */
    var resultArray:Array = [];

    /* loop through the string */
    var a:Number = 0;
    while (a < str.length)
    {
        var first:Number = str.length;
        var bLen:Number = delimiters.length;

            /* loop through the delimiters */
        for (var b:Number = 0; b < bLen; b++)
        {
            var delimiter:String = delimiters[b];

                /* find the first delimiter */
            var index:Number = str.indexOf(delimiter, a + 1);

            if (index != -1 && index < first)
                first = index;
        }
        if (first == a)
            break;
        /* Add the substring to the return array */
        resultArray.push(str.substring(a, first));
        a = first+1;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trace(("3x5+5x3+6x8-6x3-2x8+3x5").split("-").join("+").split("+"));
//output ==  3x5,5x3,6x8,6x3,2x8,3x5
```